# Extract a part of a string in c

Tags: c, string, substring

How to extract only the date part from a char* ?

```
   char *file = "TEST_DATA_20141021_18002.zip"

   char *date ="20141021"
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the format of that file name of yours is consistent you could do it pretty easily with `strtok` using `_` as the delimiter ...

Comment: @dragosht gave you a good idea. After doing that, find a token that consists of 8 symbols of numbers, that's it.

Comment: @dragosht there are 2 types of file name.                         char *file ="TEST_DATA_BIG_20141021_1800211.zip"

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char *file = "TEST_DATA_20141021_18002.zip";
    char date[16];
    char *s = file, *d = date;
    while(!isdigit(*s))
        ++s;
    do{
        *d++ = *s++;
    }while(isdigit(*s));
    *d = 0;
    puts(date);
    //or
    sscanf(file, "%*[^0-9]%15[0-9]", date);//0-9 : 0123456789
    puts(date);
    return 0;
}
```